# Exportar excel con Phpspreadsheet ,Esta página no funciona HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: excel, phpspreadsheet, host, error500

Estoy usando **Phpspreadsheet** en una pagina para exportar excel. Funciona en localhost pero en un host no, me sale el error **"Esta página no funciona HTTP ERROR 500"**.

Este es mi código.

```
<?php
    
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
      
    $id_c_dep_sesion = $_GET['user_creacion'];
    $fecha1 = $_GET['fecha1'];
    $fecha2 = $_GET['fecha2'];
    $cargo = $_GET['cargo'];
    $usuario = $_GET['usuario'];
    
    $fecha2 = date("Y-m-d");
    //sumo 1 día
    date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha2."+ 1 days")); 
    
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\SpreadSheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
    use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
    
    
    $spreadsheet = new SpreadSheet();
    $spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator("Eucaliptus")->setTitle("Mi Excel");
    
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $hojaActiva = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    
    $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
    $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(9);
    
    //---------------------------
    
    $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('Paid');
    $drawing->setDescription('Paid');
    $drawing->setPath('../public/imagenes/eucaliptuslogo.png'); /* put your path and image here */
    $drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
    $drawing->setOffsetX(0);
    $drawing->setRotation(0);
    //$drawing->getShadow()->setVisible(true);
    //$drawing->getShadow()->setDirection(5);
    $drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
    
    //-----------------------
    
    
    //------------
    
    
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A1','EMPRESA INDUSTRIAL EUCALIPTUS - COSSMIL');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:I1'); // conbina celdas 
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A2','AREA: PLANIFICACIÓN');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A2:I2'); // conbina celdas 
    $hojaActiva->setCellValue('A3','RESUMEN EJECUTIVO SEMANAL DEL:');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A3:I3'); // conbina celdas 
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A4:I4'); // conbina celdas 
    
    //centrear texto en celda
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    
     
    
     
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Mi excel.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    
    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    ?>
```

Comment: Un error 500 es un error de servidor y puede ser causado por múltiples causas. Normalmente tiene que ver con la ejecución del script, el cual puede estar usando funciones obsoletas, u otras causas.  Debes intentar acceder al log de errores de tu servidor, si tienes acceso, y ver con más detalle la causa, pues allí aparecerá mejor documentada. Es probable que hayan divergencias entre versiones de PHP o el uso de modulos de apache que no esten presentes en tu host y sí en tu localhost. Revisa eso y actualiza tu pregunta con los nuevos datos. Poco más podemos hacer desde aquí sin más información.

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser un tema de permisos en los directorios, dado que el usuario web debe crear un archivo; en este caso la hoja de cálculo

Comment: Saludos, puesto a que sin tener el log o un mensaje de error más exacto del problema no es posible dar una respuesta precisa que solucione el error de OP, por lo mismo por el momento tu respuesta es considerada de baja calidad, lo más correcto en este caso es pedir más información a quien pregunta. ;)